# Access to classes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, namespaces

I am not sure where/how to search for this question so I thought asking the comminuty of stackoverflow is the best bet.

Basically I am designing a Project which will simply provide a logic project access to a LINQ to SQL model to perform CRUD on a database. So within the Data project I have the LINQ to SQL model class and a C# class to provide access to the Model as shown below

```
public class Connection : IDisposable
{
    private DataModelDataContext _model;
    public DataModelDataContext model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { throw new Exception("Object \"model\" is not allowed to be created outside of its container class", new NotSupportedException()); }
    }

    public Connection(string username, string password)
    {
        User u = _model.Users.Where(u => u.Username == username && u.password == u.Password);

        if (u == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("User credentials are invalid", new AuthenticationException());
        _model = new DataModelDataContext();
    }

    public void refreshAndKeepChanges(object entity)
    {
        _model.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, entity);
    }

    public int getChangesCount()
    {
        return _model.GetChangeSet().Deletes.Count() + _model.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Count() + _model.GetChangeSet().Updates.Count();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _model.SubmitChanges();
        _model.Dispose();
    }
}
```

What I want is, when I compile the DLL is for the Logic project to have access to the Connection class (above) but not the DataModelDataContext (as this would defeat the object of passing user credentials).

My question is how can expose the Connection class (as public which I have already done) but hide LINQ to SQL data model from the DLL but allow the Connection class access to it???

using an extra namespace for the LINQ to SQL model does not work, i have found adding the DLL allows access to all the namespaces within the project.

Comment: If the setter throws an exception all the time, why not just remove it? Also, your use of inner exceptions is really strange. The idea of an InnerException is to describe the error that generated the exception. If you're just newing two exceptions, it doesn't make any sense to use an inner exception.

Comment: I will be using the InneException in more detail, it just has not been implemented yet, I merely used the exception code above in the setter to show I will be throwing exceptions if a user for the DLL tries setting the _Model(Model) object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `model` property to be internal, along with the `DataModelDataContext` class (which is probably done by editing the DBML, either in the designer or by hand). It's fine for the `Connection` class to know about internal classes - it just can't expose them publicly.

As a couple of asides:

- If the `model` setter is never going to be functional, why have it at all? Just get rid of it.
- You should start following the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx)

Comment: the logic Project will have access to the _model property through the connection class (via model) which represents the DataContext, I just decided to throw an exception on the setter for security, not aware if not including a setter altogether throws an exception by default.

Comment: @MrsNezbit: I thought you didn't *want* the Logic project to have access to the DataContext - which is why I said you should make `model` internal. And removing the setter means that code trying to set the value won't even *compile*, let alone run.

Comment: No. the logic project will have access to the instance of the DataContext (_model) within the Connection class, what I want to prevent is the logic Project adding the Data Project DLL and creating an instance of the DataContext to gain access to the Data without specifying any user credentials... does this make sense? I must admit while typing I am almost confusing myself. saying that using internal on the DataContext rather than public has worked, so both of these answers solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: @MrsNezbit: If the Logic project needs access to the `model` property, then it *must* know about the `DataContext` class. You could potentially have internal constructors of course - but I would hope that there were more lines of security between your code and the data than just .NET accessibility...

Comment: I undertand what you are saying, but if someone writes a project to accessing a databae through my Data Project they will be able to make calls to the database without any credentials. This is why i have opted only to expose the DataContext when valid user credentials are passed to the contructor.

Comment: @MrsNezbit: So does your database itself not perform the user validation? If not, it **really** should do. Performing the validation on the client side is really not a good idea.

Comment: At the moment no, but it will eventually be performing validation on both client/server side. I am simply looking at client side at the moment. You may see a server side question from me on hre sooner or later lol

Answer (score 1):

You change `public DataModelDataContext model` to either

```
internal DataModelDataContext model
```

if you want it to be "public within that assembly, but private to all other assemblies"

```
protected DataModelDataContext model
```

or

```
private DataModelDataContext model
```

if you don't want to expose `DataModelDataContext` to other classes in that assembly.

Most likely you want it as `internal`.

The term you can search for (or read more directly on MSDN) is [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).